# Get average for values in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have to create a function called read_data that takes a filename as its only parameter. This function must then open the file with the given name and return a dictionary where the keys are the location names in the file and the values are a list of the readings.

The result of the first function works and displays:

```
{'Monday': [67 , 43], 'Tuesday': [14, 26], 'Wednesday': [68, 44], ‘Thursday’:[15, 35],’Friday’:[70, 31],’Saturday’;[34, 39],’Sunday’:[22, 18]}
```

The second function named get_average_dictionary that takes a dictionary structured like the return value of read_data as its only parameter and returns a dictionary with the same keys as the parameter, but with the average value of the readings rather than the list of individual readings.  This has to return:

```
{'Monday': [55.00], 'Tuesday': [20.00], 'Wednesday': [56.00], ‘Thursday’:[25.00],’Friday’:[50.50],’Saturday’;[36.50],’Sunday’:[20.00]}
```

But I can not get it to work. I get the following errors:

```
line 25, in <module>
    averages = get_average_dictionary(readings)
line 15, in get_average_dictionary
    average = {key: sum(val)/len(val) for key, val in readings.items()}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is the code I have at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def read_data(filename):
    readings = {}

    with open("c:\\users\\jstew\\documents\\readings.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split(',')
            if not key in readings.keys():
                readings[key] = []

            readings[key].append(int(val))

    print(readings)

def get_average_dictionary(readings):
    average = {key: sum(val)/len(val) for key, val in readings.items()}

    print(average)


FILENAME = "readings.txt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        readings = read_data(FILENAME)
        averages = get_average_dictionary(readings)


        # Loops through the keys in averages, sorted from that with the largest associated value in averages to the lowest - see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted for details
        for days in sorted(averages, key = averages.get, reverse = True):
            print(days, averages[days])
```

Comment: your `read_data` is not `return`ing anything, just printing. So `readings = read_data(FILENAME)` is `None`

Comment: what should I do to get it to return a dictionary

Comment: As @Chris stated, change `print(readings)` to `return readings`.

Comment: Or add `return readings` as a last line of each function in case you want them to both print and return. Don't forget to change `get_average_dictionary` as well ;)

Comment: Actually, I don't think that was all of it. You had two other parts which I noted, below.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
di={'Monday': [67 , 43], 'Tuesday': [14, 26], 'Wednesday': [68, 44], 'Thursday':[15, 35],'Friday':[70, 31],'Saturday':[34, 39],'Sunday':[22, 18]}
```

You can do:

```
>>> {k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in di.items()}
{'Monday': 55.0, 'Tuesday': 20.0, 'Wednesday': 56.0, 'Thursday': 25.0, 'Friday': 50.5, 'Saturday': 36.5, 'Sunday': 20.0}
```

The error you have seems to be that you are returning nothing from your function. Just do:

```
def a_func(di):
    return {k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in di.items()}
```

And you should be good to go...

Comment: This isn't the issue. His last question answered what you're doing. This issue is for the reason in the comment.

Comment: The OP's code has `average = {key: sum(val)/len(val) for key, val in readings.items()}` I think it's safe to say they already know how to do this. Having said that, the title of the question is misleading.

Comment: I sometimes type faster than I read. Thanks for the comments. I fixed that...

Answer (score 0):

You were close but had at least one problem. One was this:

`Friday’:[50.50],’Saturday’;[36.50],’Sunday’: [22, 18]`

Notice ’Saturday’ is followed by a semicolon, not a colon. That's in both examples. Also, notice your text changes color from red to blue. That usually (this case included) means that you switched from single quotes to something like smartquotes or a character that looks like a normal quote but isn't recognized as such.

```
{'Monday': [67 , 43], 'Tuesday': [14, 26], 'Wednesday': [68, 44], ‘Thursday’:[15, 35],’Friday’:[70, 31],’Saturday’;[34, 39],’Sunday’:[22, 18]}
```

Once those are cleared up you just have to deal with the last part, returning vs printing the result.

```
def get_average_dictionary(readings):
    return {k:(sum(v)/len(v)) for (k,v) in vals.items()}
```